# What tables are needed for a Wordpress setup?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

Hello Guys I am new to wordpress and new to other CMS platforms as well and I am wondering if you could give me some tips of advice. I am building a classified ads website and I am wondering where should I create a table on my database for the items that is posted and the users as well?

Should it be on the same wordpress DB? 
Should I create a new DB?
How can I manage the user's and posts?

Thank you guys any help would be appreciated long as you are making a sense.

Comment: wordpress when installed automatically create all the user table  and content  table  you  use then according  to you requirment and customisation .  other  way if you need  to create  more table separatly for your custom requirment  then you need to create that  in  your wordpress database.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create a table, just a database. Upon accessing the WordPress for the first time it will add all the tables you will need to the database.